# Android NDK Android.mk location in Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio-2.3

When generating a new project with NDK support in Android Studio 2.3.2 you no longer get an `Android.mk` file auto-generated in the `jni/` dir.

You now get a `CMakeLists.txt` in the `cpp/` dir.

There is no `jni/` dir any more.

If you still wish to use an `Android.mk` file with `ndk-build` rather than `CMake` where does the file go?

Should it be created in the `cpp/` dir?

Or does it go in the `app/` dir same as the `CMakeLists.txt`?

Do you have to delete the `CMakeLists.txt` file if you create an `Android.mk` file if you intend for Android Studio to auto-build the native shared lib rather than running `ndk-build` explicitly?

Update - Linking to 3rd party libs:

I've generated a bunch of libusb .so files, i.e.

```
  ~/projects/third-party/libusb-1.0.21/android/libs:
  total used in directory 36 available 265852464
  drwxrwxr-x 9 bph bph 4096 Jun  2 22:20 .
  drwxr-xr-x 5 bph bph 4096 Jun  2 22:20 ..
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 arm64-v8a
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 armeabi
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 armeabi-v7a
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 mips
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 mips64
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 x86
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph 4096 Jun  5 14:05 x86_64
```

contents of mips64/ for example looks like:

```
~/projects/third-party/libusb-1.0.21/android/libs/mips64:
  total used in directory 276 available 265852464
  drwxrwxr-x 2 bph bph   4096 Jun  5 14:05 .
  drwxrwxr-x 9 bph bph   4096 Jun  2 22:20 ..
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  14872 Jun  5 14:05 dpfp
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  14944 Jun  5 14:05 dpfp_threaded
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  27432 Jun  5 14:05 fxload
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  10680 Jun  5 14:05 hotplugtest
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph 127544 Jun  5 14:05 libusb1.0.so
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  10624 Jun  5 14:05 listdevs
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  10712 Jun  5 14:05 sam3u_bphchmark
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  14912 Jun  5 14:05 stress
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 bph bph  35640 Jun  5 14:05 xusb
```

i.e. the cross-build .so file is in there..

In CMakeLists.txt my link_directories looks like this:

```
link_directories( ~/projects/third-party/libusb-1.0.21/android/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/
```

My target_link_libraries looks like this:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       usb-1.0 )
```

But I'm getting linking errors:

```
~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/mips64el-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../mips64el-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
```

Its as though the link_directories isn't getting picked up, or ${ANDROID_ABI} isn't working?

The mod to the build.gradle file wouldn't have any bearing on linker errors right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build.gradle file (the app) add an `externalNativeBuild` **outside** of the `defaultConfig` and `buildTypes` with a `path` that points to the Android.mk file.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path file("../../gameSource/Android.mk")
    }
}
```

---

Also, consider switching to CMakeLists.  It builds so much faster.

---

*Edit* : Hack the Android.mk so that when you run ndk-build it prints out a list of files instead building the library.

```
$(info "--sources--")
$(foreach file,$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES),$(info $(file)))
$(info "--headers--")
$(foreach file,$(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES),$(info $(file)))
```

Then comment out the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` command near the end of your script.

Run ndk-build as you normally would, but redirect the output to a file using `> out.txt`.

These are the source files and include directories, create a CMakeLists.txt file in a subdirectory named 'libusb' of your project where your main CMakeLists resides and start configuring and adding the files to a library target.

```
set( USBLIB_SRC 
    ... # source files
)

set( USB_LIB_INC
    ... # include dirs
)

# Copy these flags from the USBLib Android.mk
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D__ANDROID__ -DANDROID -D(etc...)")

add_library(libusb STATIC ${USBLIB_SRC})
target_include_directories(sexykanji PUBLIC ${USBLIB_INC})
```

Then, in your main CMakeLists, include the 'libusb' directory:

```
#########################################################
# import libusb library
#########################################################
add_subdirectory(libusb)
```

And add the name of the library we set earlier to your `target_link_libraries`.

---

***Edit***: Add prebuilt `.so` to CMakeLists.

```
include_directories( ../../libusb/include  ... )
link_directories(
    ../../libusb/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/
    ...
)

target_link_libraries(
                        usb
                        ...
)
```

In the Gradle file, inside of `defaultConfig`:

```
    sourceSets{
        main {
            // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
            jniLibs.srcDirs += '../../libusb/lib/'
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had already gone down the CMake path but then got stuck trying to cross build libusb. The android help in the libusb tarball is .mk based. Can you call an .mk file from CMakelists.txt?

Comment: No, but what I've done in the past is to generate file lists by hacking the Android.mk file to spit out the files in the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` and the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`.  I'll edit my answer for a quick demo.

Comment: bearing in mind i've managed to cross-build the libusb lib using the provided .mk file, is it possible for me to just specify the location of the .so file in my project CMakeLists.txt and have it bundled up into the .apk? In other words, maybe I don't have to build it 'all at once', I can build the libusb separately from my project and then just ensure my project knows that it needs that lib, and the location of the lib?

Comment: i.e. a CMake version of this -> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html

Comment: Absolutely. use `link_directories` in CMakeLists.txt to add the directory where you store your prebuilt `.so`, preferably with sub directories like `../../libusb/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/`.  When you add the library to the `target_link_libraries` you can specify the full file name like `libusb.so` OR you can leave off the 'lib' prefix and the '.so' extension.  Finally, you will need to modify your gradle file to copy the `.so` to the apk.  Let me expand answer.

Comment: hmm struggling to get the linker stage working - have updated the OP with some detail

Comment: make sure that `libusb.so ` is listed after the code that uses it.  Linker order is sometimes important.

Comment: When I added the boost library(static build), I used same lines as you do in the cmakelists.txt, but no header files included